# Error while playing 3gp video stream in some phones

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview, 3gp

Getting error while playing/streaming  3gp format in some phones (Motorola Droid /Galaxy S) but the video is playing without any problem in Nexus 1.

How can i resolve this issue other than using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the specific codecs that are used in the 3gp files. You can use ffmpeg or mplayer to inspect and tinker with files. Compare those codecs with the spec sheets for the phones and ensure you're using a codec that is on both.

Also, in order to stream video via HTTP, you need to have your header information at the beginning of the video file. ffmpeg comes with a tool called `qt-faststart` which can modify your files in that way.

Also: 3gp are essentially mp4 files, with a limited set of codecs. They're supposed to be interoperable, but I suspect it's possible to create an incompatible 3gp file by using some particularly advanced codecs.

Comment: I was trying to stream a 3GP video. 
ffmpeg that is a very good option, but if i need implement ffmepg this i need to write whole JNI wrappers..

i guess only HTC phones have native support for these kind of files

Comment: I wasn't recommending implementing ffmpeg, but just using ffmpeg as a tool for evaluating the codecs used in the particular 3gp video you were streaming. 3gp (and mp4) is just the container format for the video. Within the 3gp container can be multiple codecs for the audio and video components. Check wikipedia on the subject for more details.